# Aceptar subdirectorio con o sin "/" al final

Tags: .htaccess, url

Tengo este codigo htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ app.php?id_res=$1&pagina=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,-_]+)$ app.php?id_res=$1&pagina=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Sirve para que al poner por ejemplo http://mipagina.com/juan/ me muestre app.php...
hasta alli todo bien, funciona al 100%, el problema viene cuando yo no pongo el "/" al final (http://mipagina.com/juan) me sale que no existe la url

**Notas:**

- el `&%{QUERY_STRING}`  sirve para detectar los ?get1=....
- e provado colocando "?" despues de la barra, pero nada

El que me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceria bastante

**Mas informacion**

- Lo que deseo no es redireccionar mipagina.com/juan a mipagina.com/juan/app.php, lo que busco es que cuando accedan a esta url mipagina.com/juan me muestre (internamente) app.php.
- estoy creando una url por subdominios pero cuando accedo a la url sin "/" al final me aparece que no existe la pagina, osea no me la lee.

Comment: Hola, veo que si dejas de poner el último / la últim palabra será el nombre de tu php y será muy diferente a app.php...  yo te sugiero probar con 1: ^(?:.*)$  ó ^(?:.*)app.php$ puedes dar más detalles para tener más claro tu problema?

Comment: la página es http://mipagina.com/juan/  o es http://mipagina.com/juan/app.php?

Comment: la url es mi pagina.com/juan

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esta expresión regular.

```
^(.*)[^\/]+$
```

o en caso de querer tener el agrupador de texto completo usa esta:

```
^((?:.*)[^\/]+)$
```

La explicación es:

```
^"Cualquier símbolo del alfabeto"(.*)"que finalize en la repeticón de cualquier símbolo del alfabeto excepto /"[^\/]+$
```

Puedes verificar aquí:

https://rubular.com/r/7AhHlzw37ed2W3

La RegEx solo reconoce:

```
<SI>https : //subdomain.domain.com.country/basepage/url1/url2
<SI>https : //subdomain.domain.com.country/juan
<NO>https : //subdomain.domain.com.country/juan/
<SI>https : //subdomain.domain.com.country/juan/juan
<NO>https : //subdomain.domain.com.country/juan/juan/
```